# MVC 4 Authorization and strange redirection behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize

I'm in the final stage of my MVC 4 project , adding the authorization to the controller, start causing the redirection to home page each time the user made the submit or request and either he was logged in or out , any idea can help here?

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(uoffer uoffer, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>  fileupload)
    {
    }
```

Comment: check the web.config file for <form loginurl=''/>.

Comment: Can you give a little more details of exactly what is happening and specifically how you are logging the person in?

Comment: @tiru This is the tag <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />

Comment: @NickLarsen currently External Authentication,i will try simplify the problem tomorrow and upload the sample online thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally I figure it thank for fiddle tool, for any one having same behavior, please Notice that the log-off method is made through form submitting.
In my case i was having another block of code doing form.submit() method, my mistake was that I didn't scope and make more specific .
I mean instead of **$('form').submit()... it should be $('form#formID').submit()** >
Since the first one was general scope and when I was trying to firing it, it was triggering The Log Off form instead of My form.

Answer (score 1):

delete one of the duplicate attributes - [HttpPost] = [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)].  Then are you using [Authorize] on the Get?  You need to have the user authenticated before you try to POST.

Comment: Okay here sample of the problem it related to [Authorize] , just check here  

1-go to (http://mindsshare.com)[1]  

2- login and choose sell option  
3- click "Create" without filling information , and you will redirected to the home page !  

note :  

removing [authorize] from class preventing the redirection behavior !!

Comment: I would add [Authorize] to the GET action for /Offer/Create

Comment: [Authorize] had been added , issue still same , looks like from client side... i will try to debug there

Comment: Removing the **model Validation** has fixed the issue , it turned out that some problem in validation ,causing the application to **log off**, any ideas about this case ?